# Terminal emulator an Android 2.1

Tags: android

I want add new fonts for Android. I found a tutorial that asks me to open a terminal emulator. I can't find this terminal emulator:

> On your Droid, open up a terminal emulator application -- I used
>   "Android Terminal Emulator" -- and
>   type this exactly (make sure to be
>   case-sensitive and do not type
>   directions I include in parenthesis):

```
su (wait for the superuser screen, and press "yes")
mount -o rw,remount -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock3 /system
chmod 4755 /system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf
dd if=/sdcard/DroidSansFallback.ttf of=/system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf
reboot
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for Android Terminal Emulator on [Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=jackpal.androidterm) and [github](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/) by jackpal.

Comment: When I write su on the terminal I obtain  not allowed or permission denied .Did You know what can I do to write instructions?

Comment: @foufi, [Why do I get "permission denied" errors when I try to run commands in the terminal?](https://github.com/jackpal/Android-Terminal-Emulator/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions) You should root your phone first.

Answer (score 2):

your android has to be rooted if its not  rooted then that permission will come up